# Rewrite the Scheme code in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, racket

```
(define unique 
    (lambda (L) 
       (cond ((null? L) L) 
           ((null? (cdr L)) L) 
           ((eqv? (car L) (car (cdr L))) (unique (cdr L))) 
           (else (cons (car L) (unique (cdr L))))))
```

This above code(#racket language) finds the unique elements from the list. I want to translate this racket code into OCaml. 
So far I've got to

```
let rec unique func lis = 
        match lis with
        | [] -> []
        | (h::lis') -> if lis = []
              then x (* There is only one item in the list which was captured by head and the tail is null *)
```

This code is not right. It has left out the else statement, which I am stuck at.

Comment: The list should be sorted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translated your algoritm in OCaml gives me :

```
 let rec unique l = match l with 
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x :: y :: tl -> if x = y then y :: unique tl else x :: unique ( y :: tl);;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to use that algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer but I think that algorithm works only on a sorted list.

Comment: So the last condition that you have covers "((eqv? (car L) (car (cdr L))) (unique (cdr L))) "?

Comment: The last pattern matching with the associated expression covers the two last lines of your scheme algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the effort we are almost close to the answer. One thin is that (unique (a a b c)) the answer should be "(a b c)", but our OCaml answer only gives "b"

Comment: Sorry but you want to mean "b c", not "a" because "a" appears twice in the list.

Comment: No it should contain "a" as well. What it does is if it find duplicates it will only take one and add to the list.

Comment: Another example would be (unique '(a b a b a c)) the result would be "(a b a b a c)" as long as they are not followed by different characters you want to add that to the list.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the scheme code there are four cases.

`((null? L) L)`, that nicely corresponds to `| [] -> []` in your OCaml code.

`((null? (cdr L)) L)` checks if the list has only one element, the OCaml code for it is `| [x] -> [x]`

If it has two or more elements, you check if the first and second elements are the same.

If they are, the answer is `(unique (cdr L))`;
if they are not, it is `(cons (car L) (unique (cdr L)))`.

You can use pattern matching to get the first two elements, like this: `| first::second::rest -> if ...`